# How to assess mediation effect in multinomial logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, spss, multinomial-distribution, mediation

I wonder if it possible to include a mediation effect in multinomial logistic regression. I have a categorical (3 categories) outcome variable and four predictors (all continuous). I expect one of the predictors (X1) to mediate the relationship between the outcome variable and another predictor (X2). I also expect direct effects of X1 and X2 on the outcome.

Apparently, I could not see an option of running the regression in two steps (or blocks). Is there a way of including mediation in this analysis?  I would be glad if you could inform me how it is possible.

thanks,

PS: I am using PASW 18 for Mac.

Comment: I thought the blocks in the regression commands just ran sequential models. Is there any reason why running the models separately will not suffice?

Comment: Estimates of logistic regression do not work like OLS, and adding variables that are unrelated to the existing predictors will also impact the size of the existing predictors' coefficients. This makes comparing coefficients across separate models unreliable.